# Intellij doesn't recognize my Java application in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am new to gradle and loaded an existing Java project with gradle. I can use:

```
./gradlew build 
./gradlew run
```

to build and run the application successfully without a problem, but I can't run it in IntelliJ by right-click the Java file with the 'main' method, because when I right click the file, it doesn't show me anything like 'run as Java application'. And as a test, I want to create a "Hello World" java application (a java file) under the same project, but I can't do that, because when I click 'new' in IntelliJ, it doesn't give me any option of creating a Java class or package.

It seems like the IntelliJ doesn't recognize the project environment as java, so it can't do it. I used to use Maven.

Comment: Did you import the project from `build.gradle` file in IntelliJ IDEA? Were there any errors when importing? Also check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for exceptions.

Comment: @CrazyCoder. Yes, that does make a difference, and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project has to be imported from the `build.gradle` file. This way IntelliJ IDEA will configure all the source roots and the dependencies automatically.